# Cross-browser fix for screwed up line-height in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, typography, css

Check out the "Signs of Hope" hero text in IE8: [removed]

Do I have to hack away at a conditional stylesheet, or is there a better, IE8-compatible way to do this typography?

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the issue along with your relevant code, otherwise some people won't be able to replicate your issue

Comment: IE9 looks about the same as Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Thanks guys, my IE was set on compatibility mode. That's a relief but I still need it to work in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've figured this out, but for future knowledge seekers I'm going to guess the whole text was set to some particular line-height, despite different font-sizes.

The white text needs one line-height and the green should have another; or you can just remove line-height, or set it to normal, and let the browser automatically handle the different text sizes.